# Thymeleaf: Redundancy in the URL

Tags: spring-boot, url, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf project that runs good except for when I added a **th:href** to take me to another html page as follows:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Surgery Waiting List</h3>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <br /> <a th:href="@{surgerywaitinglist/patientSearch}" class="btn btn-primary">Add
            Procedure</a> <br /> <br />
        <table class="table table-primary table-bordered table-striped" id="employeeTable">
            
        </table>
    </div>
    


</body>
```

The controller as :

```
@Controller
public class WaitingListController {
@GetMapping(value="/surgerywaitinglist/patientSearch")
        public ModelAndView patientSearch() {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("patientSearch");
            
            
            Patient patient =new Patient();
            mav.addObject("patient", patient);
            return mav;
        }
}
```

It should take me to "http://localhost:8080/surgerywaitinglist/patientSearch", but what happens is that I get redirected to

"http://localhost:8080/surgerywaitinglist/surgerywaitinglist/patientSearch"

As you can see :
[image]

Comment: You need a slash at the beginning of your links `th:href="@{/surgerywaitinglist/patientSearch}"`

Comment: The different types of URLs handled by Thymeleaf are documented [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#link-urls). There are examples showing the difference between "page-relative" URLs and "context-relative" URLs.

Comment: Thank you both Metroids & andrewJames... 
 I worked :)